# Anonymous DH connection with Python SSL

Tags: python, ssl, https, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to use anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384) to wrap an http connection in python. I do need to use this specific cipher suite for my application. So here's what I'm starting with.

Server:

```
import ssl
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.set_ciphers("ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384")

server = HTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
server.socket = context.wrap_socket(server.socket)
server.serve_forever()
```

Client:

```
import ssl
import http.client

context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.set_ciphers("ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384")

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("localhost", "8080", context=context)
connection.connect()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:1123)
```

Why are there no ciphers available if I'm setting the cipher on both client and server?

EDIT:
I've changed the cipher list to "ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:@SECLEVEL=0" on both client and server. Now there is a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1123)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: [Python SSL Server - Client Hello w/ only Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x003a) Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698368/python-ssl-server-client-hello-w-only-cipher-suite-tls-dh-anon-with-aes-256)

My new server code looks like:

```
sslContext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
sslContext.set_ciphers("ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:@SECLEVEL=0")
sslContext.load_dh_params("params.pem")
server = socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
server.socket = sslContext.wrap_socket(server.socket, server_side=True)
server.serve_forever()
```

with params.pem containing diffie hellman parameters with a 3072 bit key length generated and serialized by the [cryptography module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.html)